# How can I access scroll position in controlsfx GridView for JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, gridview, controlsfx

I am using a controlsfx [GridView](https://github.com/jinghai/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.java) in a JavaFX application. It shows a scrollbar when needed, but I can't find any way to determine where the scrollbar is positioned at, nor update it. I need to be able to do things like respond to a "go to the top" command from the user and scroll up; or scroll to keep the selected thumbnail visible as the user uses arrow keys to navigate through the grid. But I don't see how to get access to the current scroll position, nor manipulate it, as you can with a ScrollPane.

For example, here is a sample application that creates a GridView with 100 generated images in it. I add a listener to the "onScrollProperty", but it is never called. I also have no idea how I would cause it to scroll to a certain scroll position (0..1):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.GridView;
import org.controlsfx.control.cell.ImageGridCell;

// Demo class to illustrate the slowdown problem without worrying about thumbnail generation or fetching.
public class GridViewDemo extends Application {
  private static final int CELL_SIZE = 200;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Create a Scene with a ScrollPane that contains a TilePane.
    GridView<Image> gridView = new GridView<>();
    gridView.setCellFactory(gridView1 -> new ImageGridCell());
    gridView.setCellWidth(CELL_SIZE);
    gridView.setCellHeight(CELL_SIZE);
    gridView.setHorizontalCellSpacing(10);
    gridView.setVerticalCellSpacing(10);
    addImagesToGrid(gridView);

    gridView.onScrollProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      // Never called
      System.out.println("Scrolled...");
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridView, 1000, 600));
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(x -> {
      Platform.exit();
      System.exit(0);
    });
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void addImagesToGrid(GridView<Image> gridView) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      final Image image = createFakeImage(i, CELL_SIZE);
      gridView.getItems().add(image);
    }
  }

  // Create an image with a bunch of rectangles in it just to have something to display.
  private static Image createFakeImage(int imageIndex, int size) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i ++) {
      g.setColor(new Color(i * imageIndex % 256, i * 2 * (imageIndex + 40) % 256, i * 3 * (imageIndex + 60) % 256));
      g.drawRect(i, i, size - i * 2, size - i * 2);
    }
    return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);
  }
}
```

The needed maven include is:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.6_20</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is a screen shot of what it looks like.

[image: GridView with scrollbar]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe to late for the questioner. But after i stumbled across the same problem, after hours of investigation, hopefully useful to others...

> I add a listener to the "onScrollProperty", but it is never called.

This "works as intended". :-/ See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096847.
You have to use "[addEventFilter()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter)". See example below.

To set the scroll position is a pain. You have to get the underlying "[VirtualFlow](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/VirtualFlow.html)" object of the GridView. VirtualFlow contains methods to set the scroll position to specific rows. It's strange that GridView seems to have no API for this common use case. :-(

A "prove of concept" example how to set scroll position, for a GridView with images:

```
/**
 * Register a scroll event and a key event listener to gridView. 
 * After that navigate with "arrow up" and "arrow down" the grid.
 * @param gridView 
 */
private void addScrollAndKeyhandler(final GridView<Image> gridView) {
    // example for scroll listener
    gridView.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, e-> System.out.println("*** scroll event fired ***"));
    
    // add UP and DOWN arrow key listener, to set scroll position 
    gridView.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) oneRowUp(gridView);
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) oneRowDown(gridView);
    });
}

int selectedRow = 0; // current "selected" GridView row.
/**
 * Scrolls the GridView one row up.
 * @param gridView
 */
private void oneRowUp(final GridView<Image> gridView) {
    // get the underlying VirtualFlow object
    VirtualFlow<?> flow =  (VirtualFlow<?>) ((GridViewSkin<?>) gridView.getSkin()).getChildren().get(0);
    if (flow.getCellCount() == 0) return; // check that rows exist
    
    if (--selectedRow < 0) selectedRow = 0;
    if (selectedRow >= flow.cellCountProperty().get()) selectedRow =  flow.getCellCount() - 1;
    System.out.println("*** KeyEvent oneRowUp " + selectedRow + " ***"); 
    
    flow.scrollTo(selectedRow);
}

/**
 * Scrolls the GridView one row down.
 * @param gridView
 */
private void oneRowDown(final GridView<Image> gridView) {
    // get the underlying VirtualFlow object
    VirtualFlow<?> flow =  (VirtualFlow<?>) ((GridViewSkin<?>) gridView.getSkin()).getChildren().get(0);
    if (flow.getCellCount() == 0) return; // check that rows exist
    
    if (++selectedRow >= flow.cellCountProperty().get()) selectedRow =  flow.getCellCount() - 1;
    System.out.println("*** KeyEvent oneRowDown " + selectedRow + " ***");
    
    flow.scrollTo(selectedRow);
}
```

(Tested with javafx 15.0.1 and controlsfx 11.0.3)